# 411 content length required on IIS server but not on linux based server

Tags: iis, http-status-code-411

I have a RESTApi application which I have recently moved over to Microsoft Azure App-services. Earlier it was hosted on a Linux server. The issue that I am seeing is weird:

1. When a client using ASP.net call a POST request with no body and no content-length header explicitly passed, the request fails with `411 Content-length required error`. For the same client, the requests which were going on to the Linux server are still working fine.
2. For a client using python/PHP, the same request works on both the IIS and Linux environments.

I am unable to understand why this might be happening. I have resolved the issue by sending `content-length:0` for this API call but want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: All Azure app services running behind IIS ARR, which might perform extra HTTP validation like that. It is not surprising and you can get used to that. https://help.mollie.com/hc/en-us/articles/214017925-I-use-Microsoft-IIS-and-the-webhook-prompts-a-411-Length-Required-error-message- and http://robertgreiner.com/2013/01/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-411-length-required/

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for the clarification.